# Why Are You Supposed to Make a Different HOST and PORT Variables, And Then Use Them to Make a ADDR Variable?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, port, ip-address

Whenever I look at Python networking examples, addresses for a server are always formatted like this:

```
HOST = ''
PORT = 1776
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)
```

Does this format benefit anyone in anyway? Up until this point, I've skipped the `HOST` and `PORT` variables and just set them directly in the `ADDR` variable, as I was thinking that making extra variables is just using up resources and adding unnecessary weight to the program (albeit not much...). So is there any reason or benefit to setting my addresses this way? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`socket.create_connection` expects your address to be a 2-tuple.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.create_connection)  If you were going to create a connection, you'd supply `ADDR` as your first argument to `create_connection`.

You certainly don't have to declare two separate variables, but it could be considered more readable if it's explicit where the host and port are defined.

Comment: OK, thanks. Just wanted to make sure whether it really makes a difference or not.

Answer (score 1):

There’s no technical reason it should be done that way. I imagine it was just a style preference on behalf of the authors of the examples you looked at.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using the ADDR variable at many places and later your host name or port number changes then you will end up in changing in multiple places. So declaring the HOST and PORT as variables will allow you to change it in one place

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't preclude *why* it has to be a *tuple*.